# KNN Visualisation Feedback

Tags: machine-learning

As part of a future blog post, I'm trying to explain machine learning using the simplest visualisations and explanations possible. It doesn't seem like there are any good quality videos on the topic currently publicly available, so I'm providing animations to go along with each concept.

The first one is the KNN algorithm - my animation shows a two dimensional chart which plots two ratings against each other in order to find a final rating for another arbitrary TV show. I'm using a K value of three for the demo, and then calculating the value.

Have I made any mistakes, or perhaps alluded to any misconceptions which I should try to avoid?

Video: https://youtu.be/MXAt-Gt8QuA

Comment: Why the diagonal? i would not consider it relevant in that context

Comment: Agreed, thanks. Here's a new version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO89Pe5mVd0&feature=youtu.be